# Is this the right way to solve this "oneFiveSeven" recursive question? (not looking to be efficient)

Tags: java, recursion, computer-science

I need to write a recursive method in Java called "OneFiveSeven" which receives an integer ( 0 <= n ) and returns the minimal number of addends needed in order to express ( int n ) as the sum of one's , five's and seven's.
example: oneFiveSeven(10) = 2, 5+5.

```
public static int oneFiveSeven(int n){
  if(n < 5){
    return n;
  }
  if(n == 5){
    return 1;
  }
  if(n == 7){
    return 1;
  }
  if( n % 7 + n / 7 < n % 5 + n / 5){
    return 1 + oneFiveSeven(n - 7);
  }
  return 1 + oneFiveSeven(n -5);
}
```

I'm not sure if my code is right... what do you think?
(not looking for best complexity)

Comment: Your code seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right to me.

This is the simple (but slower) recursive version of your solution:

```
public static int oneFiveSeven(int n){
    if(n < 5) return n;
    if(n == 5) return 1;
    if(n == 6) return 2;
    if(n == 7) return 1;
    return Math.min(1 + oneFiveSeven(n - 7), 1 + oneFiveSeven(n - 5));
}
```

You can take advantage of dynamic programming to store the best possibility for each value:

```
public class Main{
    public static int[] dp = new int[1000];
    
    public static void initDp(){
        dp[0] = 0; dp[1] = 1; dp[2] = 2; dp[3] = 3;
        dp[4] = 4; dp[5] = 1; dp[6] = 2; dp[7] = 1;
        for(int i = 8; i < 1000; i++) dp[i] = -1;
    }
    
    public static int oneFiveSeven(int n){
        if(dp[n] != -1) return dp[n];
        dp[n] = Math.min(1 + oneFiveSeven(n - 7), 1 + oneFiveSeven(n - 5));
        return dp[n];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initDp();
        
        System.out.println(oneFiveSeven(10));
        System.out.println(oneFiveSeven(100));
        System.out.println(oneFiveSeven(999));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2 
16
143
```

Comment: I know , and i did evaluate... 
you can see that i only substract if(..) happen, else - 5.